# Call from Node.js using .find() to Mongodb returns empty array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've read through some of the answers similar to this question and have struggled to see how they would apply to mine. The issue I am having is that when I try to retrieve any data from my MongoDB database, it returns an empty array. I've already set my network access to 0.0.0.0/0, and it says it successfully connects to my DB when I run my backend. I was hoping someone might be able to lend a hand. The GitHub for this file is https://github.com/dessygil/des-personal-site-backend

Here is my index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const jobsRoute = require("./routes/jobs");


mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(console.log("Connected to MongoDB")).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
});

app.use("/", jobsRoute);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
    console.log("Connected to port 5000");
});
```

My Jobs model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const JobSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        startDate: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
        },
        endDate: {
            type: Date,
            required: false,
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: false,
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        duties: {
            type: [String],
            required: true,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true },
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Job", JobSchema)
```

My route file

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Job = require("../models/Job");


//Create new post
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const newJob = new Job(req.body);

    try {
        const savedJob = await newJob.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedJob);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    };
});

//Update post

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const updatedJob = await Job.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {
                $set: req.body,
            },
            { new: true }
        );
        res.status(200).json(updatedJob);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

//Delete post
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const job = await Job.findById(req.params.id);
        await job.delete()
        res.status(200).json("Post had been deleted");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});

//Get post

    router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const job = await Job.findById(req.params.id);
            res.status(200).json(job);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    });
    
    //Get all posts
    router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
        try {
            allJobs = await Job.find();
            console.log(allJobs,"you are here");
            res.status(200).json(allJobs);
        } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

The structure of my db

[image]

What is returned on postman (hosted on heroku but also doesn't work when I run locally and returns the same results

[image]

The type of data stored in jobs there is 3 documents that should show up

[image]

Comment: Did you select the `blog` database anywhere in the code?

Comment: No, I decided to try and post the same data from Blog into it, and it created a separate database called test with a new collection of jobs. I'm not sure if this will cause me issues in the future. How do I make sure that it uses a certain db? AND THANK YOU FOR THE RESPONSE :)

Comment: The usual way is to use the connection string, see: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connections